# Jquery Form Styler. Как удалить и заново добавить option в select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть простой селект, который я заполняю при загрузке страницы:

```
<select class="option_selector">
</select>
```

Заполнение:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
    $(".option_selector").append('<option>' + list[i] + '</option>')
}
```

Тут ок, но как удалить и добавить новые значения при нажатии на кнопку?
Повторный код выше, но уже на событии `click` - работает неправильно(тут уже `styler` прогрузился), а `$("select").styler("destroy")` не срабатывает ни в коде, ни в консоли браузера.

Может кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: код добавления заверни в функцию для многократного использования, удалить опции $('.option_selector').empty();

Comment: пример https://jsbin.com/wufinamupa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Вам удалить все значения надо или конкретные. Или просто перезаписывать сущетвующие целиком?

Comment: @BearVorkuta очистить селект и добавить в него новые значения, но именно при JQ Form Styler плагине

Answer (score 0):

Что-то такое хотите?

```js
$("#add").click(()=>$(".option_selector").append('<option>' + "New Item" + '</option>'));

$("#clean").click(()=>$(".option_selector").empty());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="option_selector">
    <option disabled>Выберите героя</option>
    <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
    <option selected value="Крокодил Гена">Крокодил Гена</option>
    <option value="Шапокляк">Шапокляк</option>
    <option value="Крыса Лариса">Крыса Лариса</option>
</select>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="clean">Clean</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Код будет записывать новые значения вместо старых по одной кнопке.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    let options = ''
    for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
        options += `<option>${list[i]}</option>`
    }
    $(".option_selector").html(options)
})
```